# File movement issue on NFS file system on Unix box

Tags: perl, shell, unix, copy

Currently there are 4.5 million files in a single directory on an NFS file system. As a result any read or write operation on that directory is causing a huge delay.
In order to over come this problem, all the files in that directory will be moved onto different directories based on the year of its creation.

Apparently, the find command that we are using with the -ctime option is not working because of the huge file volume.
We tried listing the files based on the year of creation and then feed the list to a script that will move them in a for loop. But even this failed as ls -lrt went for a hang.

Is there any other way to tackle this problem?
Please help.

Script contents:
1) filelist.sh

```
    ls -tlr|awk '{print $8,$9,$6,$7}'|grep ^2011|awk '{print $2,$1,$3,$4}' 1>>inboundstore_$1.txt 2>>Error_$1.log
    ls -tlr|awk '{print $8,$9,$6,$7}'|grep ^2011|wc -l 1>>count_$1.log
```

2) filemove.sh

```
    INPUT_FILE=$1  ##text file which has the list of files from the previous script
    FINAL_LOCATION=$2  ##destination directory
    if [ -r $INPUT_FILE ]
    then
       for file in `cat $INPUT_FILE`
       do
           echo "TIME OF FILE COPY OF [$file] IS : `date`" >> xyz/IBSCopyTime.log
           mv $file $FINAL_LOCATION
       done
    else
       echo "$INPUT_FILE does not exist"   
    fi
```

Comment: I don't see why you sort `ls` output. Try without the `-tr` options.

Comment: @ninjalj- even the simple ls command without the -tr options failed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [readdir](http://p3rl.org/readdir) iterator.